# Execute Actions from an open program, using another Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

i want to make a Java Application that will have a button that will execute a specific action(for example "Search") in an open program,in this specific occasion Eclipse.

More specifically, i want when i press a button on my Java Application , to execute the "Ctrl+Shift+R)" = Search action , in Eclipse, and pop-up the result.

Eclipse will be always open ,so i don't want to use the: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Eclipse.exe");

any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using Robot class

Comment: yes but how i will set the actions to focus on the Eclipse program?

Comment: Like you said eclipse is always open..so focus will be on that..right?

Comment: No,
Eclipse will be always open,but so does other programs too.